# Writing with Ruby Rspec with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, saucelabs

In regards to selenium I know that there is no way to go from one tab to the next tab on a web browser. In my case, I have a test where another tab opens from the one that I previously was on. I am trying to figure out in Ruby Code (I am using Rspec with the Selenium web driver) how it is possible to have the ability to write the code so that it could trasnfer from one tab to the next. Or, code to right click and open what I need to open in a complete new window.

Thanks!!

Comment: Controlling the browser flow is usually a bad idea. Why do you need to open a new tab? UI design should provide the tabs in one layout opposed to controlling the browser.

Comment: The website I am testing for my company upon clicking a link I have to click on for the test automatically opens the next page into a brand new tab.

Comment: It'd be good to show some of your code here.

Answer (score 0):

An example with [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#clicking-links-and-buttons):

```rb
it 'displays something', js: true do
  visit some_path
  click_on 'The second tab' # <-- The title of the tab link/button

  expect(page).to have_content 'Something'
end
```

Comment: @Mark np. Accept anwer?